# iOS10 cordova-camera-roll crashes app

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

Newest iOS 10.2, Phonegap build crashes with cordova-camera-roll version 0.2.1 plugin.

Using Phonegap version cli-6.3.0

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.3.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the new plugin cordova-plugin-ios-camera-permissions and cordova-plugin-ios-microphone-permissions solves the issue.

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ios-camera-permissions" spec="1.0.3" />
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-ios-camera-permissions

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ios-microphone-permissions" spec="1.0.0" />
```

https://github.com/pinchnzoom/cordova-plugin-ios-microphone-permissions